# Why is electric flux and electric flux density not in the expected units?

Tags: electromagnetism

Referring to [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_electromagnetism_units), I was trying to understand electromagnetism at a fundamental level. I recently discovered the D field, which is electric flux density but for some reason is more commonly called the electric displacement field.

But it was good news at first because E and D seem to be exactly corresponding to H and B where the first is field strength and the second is flux density.

However, the chart also lists flux by itself, so I did some unit analysis.

Electric flux is measured in Volt-meters = kg⋅m$^3$⋅s$^{-3}$⋅A$^{-1}$

Electric flux density (the D field) is measured in C/m$^2$ = A⋅s⋅m$^{-2}$

But this is not what you expect. You expect flux density to be flux per sq m, but Vm/m^2 does not give you the units of electric flux density according to the chart.

Note, this problem does not exist with the magnetic flux and B field. Magnetic flux is measured in weber and the B field is measured in weber/m2 which is exactly what you expect for a flux density.

Comment: $D=\epsilon \, E\Rightarrow \frac Fm\,\frac Vm = \frac CV\,\frac 1m\,\frac Vm = \frac{C}{m^2}$

Comment: @Farcher Yes but this is what I'm saying how it doesn't make sense. If flux is measured in some "unit", then flux density should be unit/m2. This is the case for magnetism where the flux is webers and the flux density is weber/m2. But for the electrostatic part, flux is in V-m and flux density is in C/m2. Volt-meters does not translate to coulombs in unit analysis.